# nativescript post request using body form-data

Tags: json, typescript, nativescript

I want to send a user JSON object to a login post url like in the screenshot from postman .
to have a successful login it must be exactly as in the screenshot, otherwise I receive user object not found in the response from the api .
So I did not succeed to send a valid user object as the requirement .

I get successful login only with postman . I need a solution for nativescript (typescript)

[postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDbrJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

`multipart/form-data` is not yet supported by Http module. There is an [open feature request](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/59) that you might want to follow up for updates.

Also using form data for passing simple values is not very much encouraged, if you have access to the APIs then I would suggest you to modify them to use JSON.

I believe `nativescript-background-http` plugin should work with this scenario, but haven't tried it myself. There is also a simple [plugin](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/59#issuecomment-383492014) from community that you might want to try.

Comment: In addition to what Manoj is saying, you could see these comments in the feature request https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/59#issuecomment-250094841

Comment: I dont have access to API , I just consume it as it is. In the documentation of the API its says the server only accepts an object called "user" which composed of two fields "username" and "password" . so I need to send a JSON object called user . 
nativescript-background-http didnt work